# Insert variable's value as a parameter and its value within object's function parameters

Tags: javascript, function

(If someone has a better title, go ahead)

I want to insert the value of a variable within a function's parameters.

Here's an example to show the issue. here's a sample of `strElements` value: `elements : "elm1,elm2"`

```
var p_mode = "exact";
var strElements = "elements : ";
if (typeof elements != "undefined") {
    strElements += elements + ',';
} else {
    strElements = "";
}

tinyMCE.init({
    mode: p_mode,
    /* Magic here */
    strElements
    /* other params */
});
```

I tried doing an eval and it doesn't seem to work either.

```
eval('tinyMCE.init({
    mode: '+p_mode+','
    +strElements+'
    /* other params */
});');
```

Comment: Always avoid using an eval statement, it is one of the most dangerous things you can do. Why not just pass then in as parameters?

Comment: as you can see in the first code block, this is what I tried first and it simply does not work. `Unexpected identifier ` The JavaScript interprets the variable as a parameter by itself with no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Avoid `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) at (almost) all costs. It's not at all necessary here, anyway.

```
var p_mode = "exact";

var initParms = {
  mode: p_mode
};

if (typeof elements != "undefined")
  initParams.elements = elements;

tinyMCE.init( initParams );
```